# Stop Accordion Toggle when Checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, html

So I have very little idea of jquery. I am trying to make this piece of code working from long now. I don't understand what the problem is.

Following is my html code:

```
    <ul class="accordion">
<li>
   <div> <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Administration</a></div>
    <ul class="accordion">
        <li>
            <div><input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">President</a></div>
            <ul class="accordion">
                <li>
                 <div>   <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Manager 1</a></div>
                    <ul class="accordion">
                        <li>
                      <div>      <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 1</a></div></li>
                        <li>
                        <div>    <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 2</a></div></li>
                        <li>
                        <div>    <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 3</a></div></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div>  <input type="checkbox" />Manager 2</div></li>
                <li>
                 <div>   <input type="checkbox" />Manager 3</div></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>
```

Following is my jquerycode:

```
$(".accordion > li > div").click(function () {
 $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);              
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
            if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
              $('.accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
            }
            $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
          });
$('li :checkbox').on('click', function () {
   var $chk = $(this),
    $li = $chk.closest('li'),
    $ul, $parent;
  if ($li.has('ul')) {
    $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);


}
do {
    $ul = $li.parent();
    $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
    if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
        $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
    } else {
        $parent.prop('checked', false)
    }
    $chk = $parent;
    $li = $chk.closest('li');
} while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
});
```

I got this example from a fiddle where clicking the parent checkbox will check all the children boxes. I wanted the exact same thing but in an accordion. 
The accordion is toggling fine,but when I click the parent checkbox,the entire child-accordion is collapsing. I want that only when the accordion title is clicked,the accordion should collapse. If the checkbox is checked the accordion should still stay open,but the child elements should get checked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using, event.stopPropagation(). if you pass the event object into you checkbox click handler like so $('li :checkbox').on('click', function (event) {  }; Then inside use event.stopPropagation(). should stop the event bubbling up the dom.

Comment: if possible then please share jsfiddle..?

Comment: Hi,I tried to create the jsfiddle,but in the fiddle the toggle doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check whether the click happened in a input element, if so don't do anything

```js
$(".accordion > li > div").click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('input')) { //if clicked on input element don't do anything
    return
  }
  $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active').next().slideUp(300);
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
    $('.accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
  }
  $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
});
$('li :checkbox').on('click', function() {
  var $chk = $(this),
    $li = $chk.closest('li'),
    $ul, $parent;
  if ($li.has('ul')) {
    $li.find(':checkbox').not(this).prop('checked', this.checked);


  }
  do {
    $ul = $li.parent();
    $parent = $ul.siblings(':checkbox');
    if ($chk.is(':checked')) {
      $parent.prop('checked', $ul.has(':checkbox:not(:checked)').length == 0)
    } else {
      $parent.prop('checked', false)
    }
    $chk = $parent;
    $li = $chk.closest('li');
  } while ($ul.is(':not(.someclass)'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Administration</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">President</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="accordion">
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Manager 1</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="accordion">
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 1</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />Manager 2</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />Manager 3</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Administration</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="accordion">
      <li>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">President</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="accordion">
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Manager 1</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="accordion">
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 1</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 2</a>
                </div>
              </li>
              <li>
                <div>
                  <input type="checkbox" /><a href="#">Assistant Manager 3</a>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />Manager 2</div>
          </li>
          <li>
            <div>
              <input type="checkbox" />Manager 3</div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi,One more help- I need to add plus-minus code too. If the parent is open,it should show minus symbol on the right. If the parent is closed,the minus should be updated to plus. I have tried searching this in a lot of places,not getting working code. Please help

Answer (score 0):

you can add

```
if( $('your_checkbox').is(':checked') ){
    // No slideToggle
} else {
   // slideToggle
}
```